# Magento Difference between checkout cart and checkout session

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, session

Can anyone state what is the difference between

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
```

**and**

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')** is Shopping cart model class.It's create Varien_Object.
   **Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')** is session class with 'checkout' namespace. This stores information related to the quote, guest or not (cart totals, items, checkout progress)
2. **Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')** class depends on **Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')** when adding/updating/deleting product.